# What does (myVar && foo()) mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, operators, logical-operators

```
(myVar && foo())
```

What does the above code mean? What is it equivalent to?

I think it runs on a single line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The expression evaluates to `myvar` if `myvar` is falsey, and `foo()` if `myvar` is truthy.  The following snippets are nearly identical.

```
var x = (myvar && foo());

if(myvar){ var x = foo(); } else { var x = myvar; }
```

Answer (score 4):

it is an expression that equates to "if myVar is not falsey, run the function foo()".
If it's used like this: `var x = (myVar && foo())`, the result will be:

if myVar is not falsey, x will be set to the output of foo(). if myVar is falsey, then x will be set to the value of myVar.

Comment: If myvar is truthy x is not set the true, its set to the value of foo(), whatever that might be.

Comment: This is not quite right.  If myVar is 0, then x is set to 0, not false.

Answer (score 3):

The foo() function will only be called if myVar is not *falsey*:  meaning it can't be false, "", 0, null, or undefined.  (Any others?)

It's more typical to see an example like this:

```
window.console && console.log("some helpful debug info");
```

This is interpreted as follows...

"If the 'window' variable has a member called 'console'..."

(It's important to prefix 'console' with 'window.' because, if console is undefined, you'll get a JavaScript error instead of false.)

"... invoke the 'log' method on the 'console' object."

Comment: *"Any others?"* Just -0 and NaN, I think.

Comment: @Jason: `0`, `NaN`, a zero-length string, `undefined`, `null` and of course `false` are *falsy*...

Comment: Ah, thought about NaN as I was writing, but forgot to type it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The expression is making clever use of short circuiting in boolean expressions.  foo() will only execute if myVar evaluates to `true`.

```
if (myVar) {
    foo();
}
```

is much clearer.  There are probably cases where this sort of code makes sense, but style checkers (if you're interested in that sort of thing) will throw a fit over it.  See http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html.  It's a good practice to avoid relying on semicolon insertion and expression statements.

edit: Note that `var x = a && b();` probably isn't such a bad idea in certain contexts.  However, `(a && b())` by itself is wrong in several ways. (semicolon insertion, expression statement, aside from being semantically cryptic)

Comment: "Exploiting" "stupid" those are some strong words :) If you use JS a lot, it makes sense and is clear as it stands.

Comment: There are certainly circumstances where such code is not stupid by any reasonable measure. Such as in the context of `if (enabled && isVisible()) ...` or some such situation.

Comment: Strong words indeed! :)  However, if it were written sensibly, this question wouldn't even need to exist, would it?  Quoting Crockford, "JavaScript allows any expression to be used as a statement. This can mask some errors, particularly in the presence of semicolon insertion."  http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html

Comment: @Grumdrig Yup! That does read quite well.  However, this is an expression statement, and not a very clearly written one at that.

Comment: Editing answer to seem like less trollbait.

Comment: there is really no practical difference between a variable and a function in this case. is `if (x && y)` really any better than `if (x && y())` ?

Comment: it is not stupid to ask a question to which the answer you don't know... its stupid to presume or ignore it at all. besides; if i say 1 + 2 = 3, or 2+1 =3 what difference would it make? the answer would always be 3. so i don't know why u insist on using the if statement as a recommended option unless browsers complain at the statement in question

Comment: I wasn't calling you stupid.  I was calling the snippet you posted out on bad style and practice.

Comment: jQueryUI's code uses the `condition && action()` idiom a lot. And yes, in my opinion it is a poor practice.

Answer (score 0):

when && are evaluated the left hand is evaluated first i.e. `myVar`, if this is true then only the right hand side is evaluated i.e. `foo()`. This is because in a statement A && B if A is false then the expression A&&B will always evaluate to false.

The above statement is usually used in the following way:

```
var x = myVar && foo();
```

this can also be written as:

```
if myVar is truee x = foo(), else x = false
```