# What does shorthand "index >= 0 && count++" do?

Tags: javascript, shorthand

I was killing time reading the [underscore.string](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string) functions, when I found this weird shorthand:

```
function count (str, substr) {
  var count = 0, index;
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length;) {
    index = str.indexOf(substr, i);
    index >= 0 && count++; //what is this line doing?
    i = i + (index >= 0 ? index : 0) + substr.length;
  }
  return count;
}
```

**Legal:** Think twice before using the function above without giving credit to [underscore.string](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string)

---

I put the line alone here, so you don't waste time finding it:

```
index >= 0 && count++;
```

I have never seen anything similar to that. I am clueless in what is doing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does (myVar && foo()) mean in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2045428/what-does-myvar-foo-mean-in-javascript)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
index >= 0 && count++;
```

### First part: `index >= 0`

returns true if `index` has a value that is greater than or equal to `0`.

### Second part: `a && b`

most C-style languages shortcut the boolean `||` and `&&` operators.

For an `||` operation, you only need to know that the first operand is `true` and the entire operation will return `true`.

For an `&&` operation, you only need to know that the first operand is `false` and the entire operation will return `false`.

### Third Part: `count++`

`count++` is equivalent to `count += 1` is equivalent to `count = count + 1`

### All together now

If the first operand (`index >= 0`) of the line evaluates as `true`, the second operand (`count++`) will evaluate, so it's equivalent to:

```
if (index >= 0) {
  count = count + 1;
}
```

### JavaScript nuances

JavaScript is different from other C-style languages in that it has the concept of `truthy` and `falsey` values. If a value evaluates to `false`, `0`, `NaN`, `""`, `null`, or `undefined`, it is `falsey`; all other values are `truthy`.

`||` and `&&` operators in JavaScript don't return boolean values, they return the last executed operand.

`2 || 1` will return `2` because the first operand returned a `truthy` value, `true` or anything else will always return true, so no more of the operation needs to execute. Alternatively, `null && 100` will return `null` because the first operand returned a `falsey` value.

Comment: I like the explaination of `|| and && operators in JavaScript don't return boolean values, they return the last executed operand.` . Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It's equivalent to:

```
if (index >= 0) {
    count = count + 1;
}
```

`&&` is the logical AND operator. If `index >= 0` is true, then the right part is also evaluated, which increases `count` by one.
If `index >= 0` is false, the right part is not evaluated, so `count` is not changed.

Also, the `&&` is *slightly* faster than the `if` method, as seen in [this JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/ifs-vs-expression).).

Comment: @ajax333221 Google's closure compiler also turns most `if` constructions in `&&` statements. As for the speed, it's only slightly faster in Firefox. It's unlikely that you get any improvements in speed when using `&&` instead of `if`, just for speed. Also note that JSLint complain about `&&` instead of `if`.

Comment: In that case, I will keep coding like I do and let the compilers do the job. The last thing I want is to debug hours because of a code I am not very familiar with

Comment: Keep in mind it's more than a matter of style: the expression as an && statement allows the result to be assigned or passed as an argument.

Comment: @RobW fix the link of "this JSPerf" -> remove ")."

Answer (score 4):

It's the same as:

```
if(index >= 0){
    count++;
}
```

JavaScript will evaluate the left side (`index >= 0`), if it's `false` the `&&` (AND) will short circuit (since false AND anything is false), thus not running `count++.

If it's (`index >= 0`) `true`, it evaluates the right side (`count++`), then it just ignores the output.