# Using '&&' as a shorthand if statement?

Tags: javascript

While I was killing time looking up Javascript shorthand patterns, I came across an interesting way of expressing an `if` statement [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319915/what-does-this-shorthand-do). The following works:

```
​var var1 = 5;
var var2 = 1;

var1 == 5 && var2++;
```

I think that's a totally cool (and shorter, cleaner) way of writing an `if` statement that only needs to do one operation. However, I ran into an issue with the following code as soon as I tried something else with it:

```
​var var1 = 5;
var var2 = 1;

var1 == 5 && var2 = 2;
```

Instead of working like the first code snippet, my test throws an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Why doesn't this work, and why is the left-hand side of my statement being called out as incorrect as opposed to the right hand?

Comment: This isn't a "totally cool (and shorter, cleaner)" way to write an `if`. It's not cleaner, and is much more unreadable and unmaintainable (you've actually proven that yourself by having to ask this question).

Comment: If you know what this means, it looks cleaner (imho) and is shorter than writing three lines. I'm still a noob so that's why I had to ask this question. Plus it's totally cool imho, you can't argue that. :)

Comment: As I said, it's not. You can write an `if` in less than three lines, and it's still readable. I can tell you're a noob, though, because you think this is better. :) Experienced people would know that maintainable, readable code is better than "cool, but hard to understand".

Comment: And if you need multiple statements in the right hand, all you have to do is `condition && (function() { statement; statement; })();`, which is so much cooler than `if(condition){ statement; statement; }` ;)

Comment: I know it sounds clever, but @Ken is right. Easy to read code always trumps clever code, even if it isn't as succinct.

Comment: Shorter code is far down the priority list behind clear, reliable and maintainable.  In this case shorter is not better.

Comment: But... but... it's just so cool. And I know you can write an `if` in less than three lines but that's also not recommended either. I'll have to keep reminding myself that `cooler != better`. Or should I say, `cooler !== better`. @KenWhite: Thanks for clarifying, writing "cool" but not readable code is a bad habit of mine. :)

Comment: still, unless you abuse it with large or complex conditions, at least for me, && its far more readable than an if.

Comment: @jarry: Nope. There are zero places where `&&` is more readable than a simple `if`. It may be fewer keystrokes, which is great if you're a poor typist or lazy, but it's not more readable. And when someone unfamiliar with the code comes in to work with it, their ability to read it becomes important; the more easily they can read and understand it, the better the code. If I can use a few more keystrokes and make it easier for someone else later, I'll spend the time typing. (The person trying to figure out what I meant later might even be me, 6 months from now, and my time is valuable. <g>).

Comment: Whether or not it's readable seems pretty subjective to me. `callback && callback.call && callback.call(this)` ... if you understand short circuiting, it shouldn't take long to figure out even if you've never seen it before. If you've seen a lot of bash scripts or similar (not to mention JS), you'll recognize it immediately.

Comment: @KenWhite: But you would recognize this pattern, wouldn't you? How is it less readable if you know exactly what it's doing anyway? If you're just doing a simple one line operation, it should be fairly easy to understand for a JS pro, and thus no less readable. :)

Comment: If you're new to the codebase, coming in blind and trying to understand tons of new code, what's easier? When you have some experience with doing that (trying to come in fresh and understand code written by somebody who does stuff they think is "cool"), you'll know why it's not always a good thing. Until then, good luck. :) Hope you have jobs that pay by the hour; it's always nice to get the overtime when you're wading through someone else's mess trying to meet a deadline. :D

Comment: Sure, `return foo && foo.bar`, what could that possibly be, I'm sure you'd just puzzle over it for hours.

Comment: It's a matter of taste, and it's not a big deal. If I came into a new project that was well documented and the code made sense, consistent syntax and variable naming conventions, etc, all nice and clean, and it used some short-circuiting here and there I would be perfectly happy. It's like leaving the braces off a single-statement `if`, or leaving out semicolons. Somebody's always going to complain, but in general nobody gives a shit.

Comment: +1 for this question - it's a really important point! I see it in a surprising amount of "production" code.

Comment: Great question and answers! Thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This doesn't work because **the `&&` operator has higher precedence than the `=` operator**. In other words, your code is interpreted like this:

```
(var1 == 5 && var2) = 2;
```

If you manually put parentheses around the assignment, it will be interpreted correctly.

```
var1 == 5 && (var2 = 2);
```

Other people will reprimand you for writing code like this, saying that is a bad idea because it makes the intent of the code harder to read--which is true, especially for people unfamiliar with this idiom--but it is important to try it out and experiment with things like this to see for yourself what happens. You've already encountered one of the annoying things about this approach.

Anyway, in cases like this, I personally prefer to use single line `if` statements, like this

```
if(condition) statement;
```

Although I'm sure others will tell you that that's bad style because you have to manually add brackets when you need more statements, this hasn't really bit me and IMO it's cleaner than using three lines just for a simple condition, like you said.

Comment: Very cool, that answers my main question. But I have another: why is `(var1 == 5 && var2)`, as the left side of the statement, being called out as incorrect, then? Isn't that the same thing as saying `if(var1 == 5 && var2 != undefined)`? That should work and the right hand get called out instead.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville `(var1 == 5 && var2)` is throwing an error because it is not a valid left-hand-side expession in an assignment. It doesn't make sense to have that as the left hand side, what would `2` be assigned to?

Comment: Oho, right, that makes sense. Thanks for clearing this up! Accepting in... 8 minutes.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville `(var1 == 5 && var2)` evaluates to a boolean, so it's like saying `true = 2`.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall not in JavaScript, unless `var2` was a boolean. `var var1 = 5, var2 = 6; var1 == 5 && var2; // 6`

Comment: @GGG Ah you're correct, my bad. Of course neither a boolean nor a number is an lvalue anyway.

Answer (score 16):

Don't be alarmed that this doesn't work as you'd expect, in fact less than a month ago Brendan Eich (Creator of JavaScript) was sharing with us that this type of use is better known as an "abusage" of the language, since this logical operator isn't meant to execute code like this, but rather it's meant to determine the value of an expression.

> "I also agree...that the && line is an abusage, allowed due to JS’s C heritage by way of Java, but frowned upon by most JS hackers; and that an if statement would be much better style..." http://brendaneich.com/2012/04/the-infernal-semicolon/

That being said, you can avoid the operator precedence issue by wrapping your statements:

```
(var1 == 5) && (var2 = 2)
```

Comment: +1 for the note about "abusage" - that's exactly what this is.

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1):

because you are using an invalid operator on the right-hand side. its trying to read the entire statement as a single variable.

Answer (score 0):

Is

```
var1 == 5 && var2++;
```

an cleaner or more understandable than this?

```
var2 += var1 === 5 ? 1 : 0;
```

In addition, the above expresses ***intent*** far more clearly than your code: the next guy who has to look at your code will see it and understand immediately what's going on, but looking at your code:

```
var1 == 5 && var2++
```

Is going to raise red flags in her head, because it looks like a bug or a some sort of typo — which means she's going to have to spend time trying to understand what you were actually trying to accomplish and whether or not the wonky code was intentional or not.

My first reaction, looking at

```
var1 == 5 && var2++ ;
```

Is that an assignment was intended:

```
var1 = 5 && var2++ ;
```

But the developer bounced the `=` key by accident, turning it into an orphaned expression (that happens to have side-effects).

Further, orphan expressions like that is likely to get flagged by any decent linter, for instance eslint's [`no-unused-expressions`](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unused-expressions) rule, as they indicate a probable bug.